# Brio save file without column headings

Tags: hyperion, brio

How can I prevent the column headings from appearing in a .txt save file in Hyperion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from Oracle/Hyperion:

You are correct that the headers still appear on the export of the section to *.xls format. If you are attempting to export the section and do not want the headers present, you will need to export out as one of the Office Archive formats that are provided (Microsoft Office 2000 HTML (*.html) or  (*.mhtml)). There is no option through the GUI to export a file in the Excel (*.xls) format and not have the headers present.

Comment: Oracle clearly hasn't spent enough time owning Hyperion to actually work with it, or they aren't willing to give you workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

On the main menu bar select Format. In the dropdown, there is an option for 'Column Titles’. Selecting the 'Column Titles' option with uncheck it, removing the column titles from the results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't remove them from the export file.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, assuming you have no duplicate rows, is to create a Pivot section for the Table/Result set, and bring in every column as a Side Label, and turn off all the Top/Side/Corner labels.  Export the Pivot section.  Works best if you're pulling in a unique identifier for each row.